# Rearrange a number into non-English alphabetical order in Raku

Tags: hash, raku

I'm trying to rearrange a number into non-English alphabetical order.

```
my @numDE = < null eins zwei drei  vier fünf sechs sieben acht  neun >;
# english   < zero one  two  three four five six   seven  eight nine >;

my %numrank; # The lookup hash: number => its_alphabetical_order

for @numDE.sort.kv -> $k,$v {%numrank{%(@numDE.kv.reverse){"$v"}} = "$k"};

my %temp; # number => reassigned order value  
%temp{"$_"}= %numrank{"$_"} for "2378".comb; # 2378 sample input
say %temp.sort(*.values); # this prints:
# (8 => 0 3 => 1 7 => 7 2 => 9) it's in order but unformatted

my %target= %temp.sort(*.values); # Attempt to print it in order
for %target.kv -> $k,$v {print $k}; # that prints in random order
```

1- How to print the `%temp` hash in order?

2- (optional) Is there a way to start using the hash variable without declaring it with `my` i.e. as it is in Python?

3- (optional) I've chosen the lookup approach to solve this problem and the resulting code looks a bit convoluted. Could the solution be made shorter using any other approaches?

Comment: Quick comment: it's not available yet, but there is work being done to provide a localized sort algorithm (initially in module space, but very likely eventually in core). I've been bad and not done the prep work yet I keep saying I will some that samcv++ can integrate into moarVM.

Comment: More on topic, on the final assignment, you're assigning back into a hash, which is unordered.

Comment: Yep. It was an attempt to print the number in ordered form but because I've spent more than an hour on the previous section I got exhausted and could not think of anything better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So there are a couple of things that I'd take a look at, but it does look like you're doing a few extra steps (in the comments you said you've tried a few different things, so I imagine you didn't initial do some many extra).

You've first given yourself the german numbers:

```
my @numDE = <null eins zwei drei vier fünf sechs sieben acht neun>;
```

Next, you want to be able to order things based on the German spelling. I'll try to use the method you've approached, but I'll show you a simplier way at the end.  Your next step is to effectively cache the sort order of them, and store it into a variable "numrank".  Building off of `@numDE.sort.kv`, we get

```
my %numrank;
for @numDE.sort.kv -> $k, $v {
    %numrank{$v} = $k;
}
say %numrank;
# {acht => 0, drei => 1, eins => 2, fünf => 3, neun => 4, null => 5, sechs => 6, sieben => 7, vier => 8, zwei => 9}
```

Okay, not bad.  Also note that while the output of `%numrank` appears to be ordered, as a hash, it is inherently unordered.  It just happens to *print* keys in alphabetical as a rule and our keys and values are sorted on those lines.  Now we just need to use the *actual* number as the key, rather than the German name instead.

```
my %numrank;
for @numDE.sort.kv -> $k, $v {
    my $id == @numDE.first: $v;
    %numrank{$id} = $k;
}
say %numrank;
```

Oops, we get the same thing.  This is because `.first` returns the actually object.  For its index, we just attach the `:k` adverb:

```
my %numrank;
for @numDE.sort.kv -> $k, $v {
    my $id == @numDE.first: $v, :k;
    %numrank{$id} = $k;
}
say %numrank;
# {0 => 5, 1 => 2, 2 => 9, 3 => 1, 4 => 8, 5 => 3, 6 => 6, 7 => 7, 8 => 0, 9 => 4}
```

Perfect, now we can see that the value for 8 (acht) is 0 as it's first, and for 2 (zwei) is 9, as it's last.  Note that we could also have used an array here, since our indices are numbers (using `@numrank` and then doing `@numrank[$id] = $k`)

Now to sort some stuff.  In your code you have

```
%temp{"$_"}= %numrank{"$_"} for "2378".comb; # 2378 sample input
```

This creates an unordered hash, wherein the name of each key is a digit, and its value is its rank.  That's basically what we had above in the first attempt at making `%numrank`.  But because `%temp` is a hash, if you have any two digits that repeat, you'll lose the extras:

```
%temp{"$_"}= %numrank{"$_"} for "222".comb;
# {2 => 9}
```

Instead, I think you want to create an array which can allow for ordering:

```
my @temp = ($_ => %numrank{"$_"}) for "22378".comb;
# ^^ both 2s are preserved
```

Now you can simply sort on the values:

```
say @temp.sort: *.values;
```

You could loop directly on this:

```
for @temp.sort(*.values) {
   print .key;
}
```

## The simpler way

```
"2378".comb.sort: { @numDE[$^digit] }
# (8 3 7 2) # acht drei seiben zwei
```

Here we sort the combed digits based on the German text form of each number.  `@numDE` as the names of the numbers, and `$^digit` is an implicit variable that holds the digit (the `[ ]` automatically coerces it to a number for us).  If you plan on using it regularly, you can actually store the block in a variable, like this:

```
my &sort-de = sub ($digit) { @numDE[$digit] };
"87446229".comb.sort: &sort-de;
# (8 9 6 7 4 4 2 2)
```

And as mentioned above, you can do the for loop directly on this, if you want to style it in some other manner:

```
for "87446229".comb.sort(&sort-de) {
   say $_
}
```

Comment: Making the `hash` using actual numbers instead of characters to have it ordered is on point. The simpler way is quite good  too. It shows practicality of the language really.  Helpful and comprehensive. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about this problem is as a translation issue:  we need to translate one ordering convention into another ordering convention.

Start by setting up the first of a pair of indices that allow ordering of numeric elements alphabetically, in German (code snippets performed in the Raku REPL):

```perl6
> my @a = @numDE
[null eins zwei drei vier fünf sechs sieben acht neun]
> my @b = @a.pairs.sort(*.values)>>.keys.flat;
[8 3 1 5 9 0 6 7 4 2]
> say @a[@b]
(acht drei eins fünf neun null sechs sieben vier zwei)
```

Above, we show that we can reorder by index `@b`. But how to get `@b` back to *its* original order? By deriving a second 'originating' index `@c`:

```perl6
> my @c = @b.pairs.sort(*.values)>>.keys.flat;
[5 2 9 1 8 3 6 7 0 4]
> say @b[@c]
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Okay, now we have the correct 'translation' that we need to solve the problem:

```perl6
> "2378".comb.trans( 0..9 => @c ).comb.sort.trans( @c => 0..9 ).trim.say
8 3 7 2
```

EDIT--Second example below:

```perl6
> "87446229".comb.trans( 0..9 => @c ).comb.sort.trans( @c => 0..9 ).trim.say
8 9 6 7 4 4 2 2
```

Basically we translate the original value to an 'originating index' value, comb, sort, and then finally we back-translate the 'originating index' value to the original.

( "8 3 7 2" is  "acht drei seiben zwei". Thanks for your examples @user0721090601 ! ).
( Note, `trim` is used to clean up some formatting issues ).

HTH.